# How to test without committing?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped

The DefinitelyTyped test script refuses to run unless everything is committed:

```sh
> npm test
..
Error: 'git diff' should be empty. Following files changed:
..
```

I find this awkward to use. While writing types I often want to try a few things and run tests to see what works before deciding what to commit. Currently this requires repeatedly committing everything, running tests, then reverting the commit.

**Is there a way to run DefinitelyTyped tests without committing?**

Comment: Committing only affects your branch
. Use `git --reset` or `git --rebase` to cleanup before you publish your changes.

Comment: Do you need any functionality of `npm test` that `npm lint your-package` does not provide ? If not you should be fine with the latter. On top of that the turnaround is considerably shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Commit your changes and then run `npm test` or `yarn test`.

If you need to make further changes, use `git --amend` to update your local commit.